# Expose Microsoft Access database over SQL Server using linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

We have one .exe application that uses one .mdb Microsoft Access database.

I need to access data inside access file over Microsoft SQL Server. We have SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise that has linked server pointed to this Access file and I can run select / update query using SQL statement.

```
SELECT * FROM [LinkedServerAccessDB]...[SomeTable]
```

How can I configure that this linked server, my Access database, is directly published as "Database" when some application tries to connect to my SQL Server using SQL Server instance name, and username and password. Which "database name" should I use to use directly linked server ?

Thank you

Comment: +1 to @p.campbell's answer below, but I'm curious why the SQL Server component is required. Is there a reason you don't want to connect to the Access file directly from the application?

Comment: Hi, yes few applications that needs to access data from this Access file, does support only directly MSSQL, and I can not change all data to MSSQL it needs to stay original in current Access file. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want your MS Access Linked Server object available as a database (i.e. available in the 'Databases' folder in SSMS). This isn't possible, directly.

Suggest you create a new SQL Server database that mimics the name of that Access database. Map a user to that login you've got above. Allow the user to run queries against the linked server.

Comment: Ok, when I create new SQL database, how to I create mimics and map login to Access then ? My application that needs that support only standard MSSQL , and i need (for other reasons) for data to stay in current shape/access database. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CREATE SYNONYM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) like so.

```
USE ASQLServerDB
GO

CREATE SYNONYM Sometable FOR LinkedServerAccessDB...SomeTable
```

Once this is done you can write `SELECT [...] from SomeTable` as though it was a member of the database ASQLServerDB

I was only able to get it to work at the object level so you'll need to do this for each object you want to expose. You could create an empty database that just contained these Synonyms if you wanted to get that "published as a database" feel.

```
 --This doesn't work
CREATE SYNONYM Sometable FOR LinkedServerAccessDB...
```

Comment: Hi, i have created manually synonim for one table now, thank you a lot, and select and update query works normally. However my applications looks inside "Tables" not Synonyms so still can not use data, for example in Sharepoint with BCS or some other application. Can somehow synonym be presented in "Tables" part in MSSQL management studio ? thank you